# NSURL returning nil (Swift 2.0)

Tags: xcode, swift2, nsurl

Any ideas why I'm getting nil for the second let?

```
if let url = NSURL (string: "https://domain.com/api/v2/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=" + urlSuffix)
        {
            do
            {
                var file: String = " "

                try file = String(contentsOfURL: url, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as String

                print("Contents of page: \n" + file) //this works correctly and displays the contents, which is another URL)

                let uri = NSURL (string:file)
                print (uri) // this fails and returns nil
```

Comment: i am not sure that type casting works there sir. thats why you get nil

Comment: I don't understand, why can't I take a string and make NSURL?

Comment: I found the error, the "file" contained special characters " (quotation mark) at the start and at the end. I fixed that and now it works.